# Draw with OpenGL offscreen

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pixel

Is there a way to use OpenGL to draw offscreen? What I want to do is this: I want to be able to use functions like glVertex, and get the result in a 2D pixel array.

I am using Python. I tried using PyGame, but it's not working very well. The problem with PyGame is that uses a window event though i don't need it. In addition, I had to draw to scene + flip the screen twice in order to access screen pixels using glReadPixels.
An other problem is that I can't have more that one window at once.

Is there any proper way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for seems to be two things in one... you want an off-screen buffer (FBO) and you want to get the contents of the framebuffer in client memory.

#### Can you indicate which version of GL you are targeting?

If you are targeting OpenGL 3.0+, then you can use FBOs (Framebuffer Objects) and PBOs (Pixel Buffer Objects) to do this efficiently. However, since you are using `glVertex`, I do not think you need to bother with efficiency. I would focus on learning to use Framebuffer Objects for the time being.

If you are not using GL3 you ***might*** have access to the old EXT FBO extension, but if you do not have that even you might need a PBuffer.

*Note that PBuffers and Pixel Buffer Objects are two different things even though they sound the same. Before GL3/FBOs, WGL, GLX, etc. had special platform-specific functionality called Pixel Buffers for drawing off-screen.*

Comment: Sorry for OT but I cannot find another way to contact Andon. Andon, the web site in your profile seems to be offline. How can I contact you?